# Select DropDown using jquery in shopify

Tags: jquery, shopify

I have Dropdown in my shopify and i wanted to change it using Jquery

i use this code

```
$('#coin-container select').val('USD').trigger('change')
```

to change the dropdown.The value of dropdown changed but the change action is not happend but when i changed with mouse click it happend

so how can I triggers the event?

Comment: Need to check, simple select element is used or any 3rd party library is used to create the custom select list.

Comment: it is simple select

Comment: Are you able to share the URL?